# select everything with different cases

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I would like to select everything from a table based on value of **active colum**

1. if active = 1 then selet *
2. if active = 0 then select nothing
3. if active is null then select based on active of parentNode

The table looks like this:

```
  mytable:
 node | parentNode | active | moreColumns
```

What I have written is

```
select *
from mytable
where active = case
           when active = 1 then 1
    case
           when active is null then (select node.active 
                                     from mytable 
                                     where parentNode = node) end;
```

The query doesnt work somehow. any suggestion?

Comment: node.active is not correct sytnax

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two different RDBMS; which are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track.  With a correlated subquery, you need to use table aliases and qualified column names -- good ideas in all queries:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.active = 1 or
      (t.active is null and
       (select t2.active
        from mytable t2
        where t2.node = t.parentnode
       ) = 1
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from mytable where 
    1 = case 
            when active = 1 then 1
            when active = 0 then 0
            when nvl(active,-1)=-1 then 
                case 
                    when parentNode = Node then 1
                    else 0
                end
        end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use a hierarchical query to find the most recent ancestor with a non-null active (and this will navigate up multiple levels of ancestors rather than just looking at the parent):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ( node, parentNode, active ) AS
  SELECT 1, null, 0    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1,    1    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2,    null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 3,    null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 1,    0    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 5,    null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 6,    null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, null, null FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( node ) AS node,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( parentNode ) AS parentNode,
         active
  FROM   mytable
  WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
  CONNECT BY PRIOR parentNode = node
         AND PRIOR active IS NULL
)
WHERE  active = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
NODE | PARENTNODE | ACTIVE
---: | ---------: | -----:
   2 |          1 |      1
   3 |          2 |      1
   4 |          3 |      1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=051d6a48502146fc923a001b977d358c)*